# Xamarin.InAppBilling - "Error available inventory: System.NullReferenceException"

Tags: xamarin, in-app-purchase, xamarin.android, in-app-billing

**Note**: I'm primarily posting this question here so that it's google indexed and spares some fellow poor soul the trouble of digging deep into this mess only to find it's not their own fault. An acceptable answer to this question would be a workaround I can use or someone at Xamarin/SimpleJson ack'ing this is a bug and it's gonna be fixed.

I've been using Xamarin.InAppBilling successfully for more than a year now (with purchases on the real Google Play store working fine). We recently started re-testing this functionality (due to a refactoring) and are getting this exception when querying our product inventory (even when using the static response test produkt Skus):

```
Error Available Inventory: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
  at Xamarin.InAppBilling.PocoJsonSerializerStrategy.DeserializeObject (System.Object value, System.Type type) [0x0047a] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Xamarin.InAppBilling.SimpleJson.DeserializeObject (System.String json, System.Type type, IJsonSerializerStrategy jsonSerializerStrategy) [0x0003d] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Xamarin.InAppBilling.SimpleJson.DeserializeObject[T] (System.String json) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Linq.Enumerable+WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2[TSource,TResult].MoveNext () [0x00064] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/2098/3efa14c4/source/mono/external/referencesource/System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs:285 
  at System.Collections.Generic.List`1[T]..ctor (IEnumerable`1 collection) [0x0008b] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/2098/3efa14c4/source/mono/external/referencesource/mscorlib/system/collections/generic/list.cs:105 
  at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource] (IEnumerable`1 source) [0x00011] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/2098/3efa14c4/source/mono/external/referencesource/System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs:835 
  at Xamarin.InAppBilling.InAppBillingHandler+<QueryInventoryAsync>c__AnonStorey0.<>m__0 () [0x00092] in <filename unknown>:0
```

I have reversed Xamarin's In App Billing code, especially the `Xamarin.InAppBilling.InAppBillingHandler.QueryInventoryAsync(IList<string> skuList, string itemType)` method.

What it does is query the Google Play Billing API for sku details and then deserializes the returned `DETAILS_LIST` json objects. This is where the code throws the `NullReferenceException`. All of this is beyond my control, so I have used a modified copy of this code to get the raw json and sure enough it looks pretty good to me. Code:

```
var service = _serviceConnection.Service;
Task.Factory.StartNew<IList<Product>>( () => {
    IList<Product> result;
    try
    {
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.PutStringArrayList( "ITEM_ID_LIST", skus );
        Bundle skuDetails = service.GetSkuDetails( 3, this.Activity.PackageName, ItemType.Product, bundle );
        int responseCode = skuDetails.GetInt( "RESPONSE_CODE" );
        if (responseCode != 0)
        {
            ViewModel.ShowTransactionError( "Error querying inventory: " + TranslateResponseCode( responseCode ) );
            result = null;
        }
        else
        {
            IList<string> stringArrayList = skuDetails.GetStringArrayList( "DETAILS_LIST" );
            result = null;
            if (stringArrayList != null)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("DETAILS_LIST: " + string.Join("\n - ", stringArrayList));
                result = stringArrayList.Select(x => JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Product>(x)).ToList();
            }                        
        }
    } catch (Exception ex)
    {
        ViewModel.ShowTransactionError( "Error querying inventory: " + ex.ToString() );
        result = null;
    }
    return result;
} )
```

Json:

```
DETAILS_LIST: {"title":"Sample Title","price":"0,93 €","type":"inapp","description":"Sample description for product: android.test.canceled.","price_amount_micros":933038,"price_currency_code":"EUR","productId":"android.test.canceled"}
 - {"title":"Sample Title","price":"0,93 €","type":"inapp","description":"Sample description for product: android.test.item_unavailable.","price_amount_micros":933038,"price_currency_code":"EUR","productId":"android.test.item_unavailable"}
 - {"title":"Sample Title","price":"0,93 €","type":"inapp","description":"Sample description for product: android.test.purchased.","price_amount_micros":933038,"price_currency_code":"EUR","productId":"android.test.purchased"}
 - {"title":"Sample Title","price":"0,93 €","type":"inapp","description":"Sample description for product: android.test.refunded.","price_amount_micros":933038,"price_currency_code":"EUR","productId":"android.test.refunded"}
 - {"title":"Boat Upgrade (Rowing in Motion - Solo)","price":"69,90 €","type":"inapp","description":"Analyze and Record an unlimited number of strokes per rowing session.","price_amount_micros":69900000,"price_currency_code":"EUR","productId":"com.rowinginmotion.mobile.boatapp.droid.solo.boat"}
 - {"title":"Coach Upgrade (Rowing in Motion - Solo)","price":"98,77 €","type":"inapp","description":"Receive unlimited live data from a boat using a mobile WiFi.","price_amount_micros":98770000,"price_currency_code":"EUR","productId":"com.rowinginmotion.mobile.boatapp.droid.solo.coach"}
```

So I suppose something is wrong with the SimpleJson/PocoJson whatever serializer they have in there. Looks like a bug in the library to me, rather than an error on my side (worked through their checklist and everything looking god here).

I'd use JSON.NET Problem is their `Product` class has apparently no default constructor (what?!, I've worked with IL for quite some years and never saw something liked this), but has a `CompilerGeneratedAttribute` stuck on it. My Products would need to be instances of that class though so that I can pass them back to their API though...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

And the [linker](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/advanced_topics/linking/) hits again. The `PocoJsonSerializerStrategy` uses plenty of reflection so this was my second guess, after working through the long list of [things you need to get right for IAPs to work](https://components.xamarin.com/gettingstarted/xamarin.inappbilling).

Add this to your `.csproj` and  you will be good to go.

```
<AndroidLinkSkip>Xamarin.InAppBilling</AndroidLinkSkip>
```

It's a real disappointment Xamarin doesn't make their own libraries linker proof...

This issue has easily cost me a day or two, in particular because there's so many [subtle ways](https://components.xamarin.com/gettingstarted/xamarin.inappbilling) in which In-App-Billing can break that you ought to check first (in particular, we moved much of our IAP logic from an Activity to a Fragment so this had to be tested as well).

Sidenote: I waited 3x2h in vain for Google Play Alpha channel updates of my instrumented builds to be available on my test devices. For *me* I can test and run IAPs successfully with builds deployed from Xamarin Studio (even Debug builds). Doesn't mean this will work for you too.